# How to convert mysql query to ruby on rails active record in multiple joins

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to ask some help from ruby on rails expert to convert this MySQL query to active record in rails.

```
 SELECT 
    products.id,
    products.product_name,
    products.price,
    IFNULL(products.quantity, 0) + IFNULL(product_in.quantity, 0) - IFNULL(product_out.quantity, 0) AS Quantity
    FROM products
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT product_id, SUM(`quantity`) AS Quantity
        FROM purchases
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) product_in ON products.id = product_in.product_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
        FROM transaction_details
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) product_out ON products.id = product_out.`product_id`
```

Comment: Hi coolshox!! You can try this tool for converting MySQL query to active record  `http://www.scuttle.io/`

Comment: Hi @RajkumarP I already tried this but does not work the conversion is not correct

Answer (score 0):

You can try `find_by_sql` from `ActiveRecord::Querying` like this:

`Product.find_by_sql(sql_query)`

More about `find_by_sql` [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql)

Comment: let me try on this

Comment: Already tried but it only get the first select but the sum of a column does not appear - <Product id: 39, product_name: "Macbook Pro 13 inches", price: 0.12e2>, #<Product id: 40, product_name: "asus gaming laptop", price: 0.12e2>, #<Product id: 41, product_name: "razer mouse", price: 0.10023e3>, #<Product id: 42, product_name: "d", price: 0.1223e4>, #<Product id: 43, product_name: "apple mouse", price: 0.8929e3>, #<Product id: 44, product_name: "asus", price: 0.8975478e5>

Comment: Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: @coolshox Have you tried `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`

Comment: yes I already tried. it's a raw query I used. It seems to work but I'm having trouble if I used gem 'wice_grid' for table. That is why I'm looking if I could translate this raw query mysql to active record in order for me to easy to used wice_grid gem.